# Receive call and dial single digit back with twilio?

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to answer a phone call and dial a single digit back depending on an input from the user, is this even possible with twilio?

edit: thanks for the downvote, if you knew the twilio API you would've known this is a valid question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

After using [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) to collect your user input you can respond with Twiml containing the [`<Play digits="1">`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) verb to play DTMF tones during a call.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather action="/process_gather" method="GET">
        <Say>
            Please enter a digit
        </Say>
    </Gather>
</Response>
```

At `/process_gather` your server would respond with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Play digits="digit to play..."></Play>
</Response>
```

Please let me know if I can help further!

Comment: Hi Eddie,thanks man, the actual problem is making twilio dial a number back, it's for a touch tone application to activate a gate after they enter a code.. i think play will just play the sounds and not dial the dialpad?

Comment: The sound you hear when you dial a key is actually a [DTMF tone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual-tone_multi-frequency_signaling), also referred to as the trademarked Touch-Tone. It's how our phone systems operate today. When you're interacting with a touch tone application, the keys you press are sending the same sound that Twilio does under `<Play>`.

Comment: Oh, this is exactly what i was looking for, perfect, thanks for the explanation sir!